# Order by with long type field not working in Spark Java Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset and below are the fields in Employee object.

```
class Employee {String loginSession, Long loginDateTimeMilli, String name , string empType, String location}
```

I have to perform below operation on the dataset

```
    group by loginSession
    order by loginDateTimeMill
```

Below is how i am performing the same

```
ds.orderBy(col('loginDateTimeMill').asc())
.groupBy(col('loginSession'))
.agg(collect_list(struct) ...) ...
```

This gives me below output (example)

```
[[loginSession, WrappedArray([name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_2] 
                              ,[name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_1]
                            ,[name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_3])]
```

Below is the expected output

```
[[loginSession, WrappedArray([name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_1]
                            ,[name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_2]
                            ,[name1,emptype1,location1,loginDateTimeMilli_3])]
```

Not sure why its not working. Am i doing something wrong ?
Any help will be appreciated.
I am using Java api for spark.

EDIT :  I am creating files for each loginSession which is working fine only issue is the details are not in sorted order. Also the issue is not with all the files generated it only appear for some.

Comment: this is to be expected, `groupBy` will not preserve order due to shuffling. You should pack `loginDateMilli` as first element in your struct, then use `sort_array`. Or, make the aggregation using Dataset API (`groupByKey`, `mapGroups`)

Comment: Depending on what you intend to do next, it may be easier simply to just order by session and date, and do the grouping based on the order.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth :  `loginDateTimeMilli` is places as first column in the wrapped array. 
if `groupBy` doesnt preseve the order, will passing the column `loginSession` in `orderBy` work as suggested by @RealSkeptic ?

Comment: My suggestion was good only depending on what you are doing with the result data. Namely, if you are collecting it to the driver or doing something else. You should add that information to the question if you want to pursue this further.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Updated with Edit.

@RaphaelRoth : I have already tried with `sort_array` and no luck Also for aggregation i have lots of columns.